# WeBid: Timezones with daylight savings time not calculated correctly

Tags: php, timezone, dst

I'm currently using an open source application: WeBid (available [here](http://www.webidsupport.com/))

Here is the issue:

- The user has a preferred timezone stored in DB
- The site has a default timezone stored in DB
- All db stored dates are stored at "GMT-0"

The application doesn't calculate the DST (Daylight Savings Time) correctly as it uses the following code:

(includes/functions_global.php)

```
$this->ctime = time() + (($this->SETTINGS['timecorrection'] + gmdate('I')) * 3600);
$this->tdiff = ($this->SETTINGS['timecorrection'] + gmdate('I')) * 3600;
```

gtpotyf explains:

> gmdate('I') -> Returns 1 if DST is active, 0 if not active. However
>   since gmdate always uses GMT(+0) and that timezone has no DST it will
>   always return 0.
>
> using date('I') instead of gmdate('I') would work better, but would
>   still not be correct since it uses the timezone from the server and
>   still not the users timezone.

No final correction was adopted by WeBid's latest version, please help me resolve this issue.

[Source](http://www.webidsupport.com/forums/showthread.php?4911-Date-and-time-problems&p=24530&viewfull=1#post24530)

Comment: GMT(+0) and GMT are not the same thing. GMT(+0) could be an UK timezone, which would be affected by DST +1. The database should store times/dates as UTC just to be sure there would be no DST complication when decoding a date to convert to a timezone.

Comment: @Tiberiu-IonuțStan: No, "GMT" is not the UK time zone. Anything interpreting "GMT" to mean "the UK time zone" is broken, IMO.

Comment: @Jon Skeet I was saying GMT+00 and GMT+01 would be interpreted as timezones instead of the reference time GMT. GMT should be written as GMT, or UTC, and not as GMT-00. I think there's something wrong right there. Also, that application (WeBit) should be saving timezones, not some "time correction". For example it should be saving `Europe/London`. See bcmcfc's answer, that's the only way this is getting fixed.

Comment: @Tiberiu-IonuțStan: Whereas I'm saying that anything which interprets "GMT+00" as equal to "Europe/London" is fundamentally broken. Any zone which is just specified as an offset from UTC (or GMT) should be treated as not observing DST. I agree that "Europe/London" is the way that the UK time zone should be stored, but I disagree that "GMT(+0) could be a UK time zone". Unless you're meaning that something is erroneously storing the UK time zone *as* GMT(+0)...

Comment: @JonSkeet When I placed the first comment bcmcfc this question was not answered. What bcmcfc is exactly what I mean by "The database should store times/dates as UTC". Also, that should be an accepted answer, I really don't see anything else that can be added (WeBid) is clearly broken in a very bad manner).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to sort out timezones properly you'll need to do a number of things.

Set your server to UTC, so that PHP's `time` and `date` functions return a UTC timestamp. (In addition to associated functions such as `strftime`.

Depending on your database, you can set its timezone to UTC as well. MySQL's documentation on the subject is [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/time-zone-support.html).

You'll need to migrate the datetimes stored in there to UTC if they aren't already. (I'm not sure what you mean by GMT-0.)

Let users choose a timezone in the format 'Europe/London' as supported by PHP's DateTimeZone class.

Following some research, I put together the following array of timezones to present to users in a drop down box, as I didn't want duplicates (Amsterdam and Brussels are in the same timezone, for example.) I wouldn't claim it to be perfect though. Depending on your user base you may want to investigate certain timezones in more detail.

```
$timezones = array(
        'Pacific/Midway' => '(UTC-11:00) Midway Island, Samoa',
        'Pacific/Honolulu' => '(UTC-10:00) Hawaii-Aleutian',
        'Pacific/Marquesas' => '(UTC-09:30) Marquesas Islands',
        'Pacific/Gambier' => '(UTC-09:00) Gambier Islands',
        'America/Anchorage' => '(UTC-09:00) Alaska',
        'America/Ensenada' => '(UTC-08:00) Tijuana, Baja California',
        'Etc/GMT+8' => '(UTC-08:00) Pitcairn Islands',
        'America/Los_Angeles' => '(UTC-08:00) Pacific Time (US & Canada)',
        'America/Denver' => '(UTC-07:00) Mountain Time (US & Canada)',
        'America/Chihuahua' => '(UTC-07:00) Chihuahua, La Paz, Mazatlan',
        'America/Dawson_Creek' => '(UTC-07:00) Arizona',
        'America/Belize' => '(UTC-06:00) Saskatchewan, Central America',
        'America/Cancun' => '(UTC-06:00) Guadalajara, Mexico City, Monterrey',
        'Chile/EasterIsland' => '(UTC-06:00) Easter Island',
        'America/Chicago' => '(UTC-06:00) Central Time (US & Canada)',
        'America/New_York' => '(UTC-05:00) Eastern Time (US & Canada)',
        'America/Havana' => '(UTC-05:00) Cuba',
        'America/Bogota' => '(UTC-05:00) Bogota, Lima, Quito, Rio Branco',
        'America/Caracas' => '(UTC-04:30) Caracas',
        'America/Santiago' => '(UTC-04:00) Santiago',
        'America/La_Paz' => '(UTC-04:00) La Paz',
        'Atlantic/Stanley' => '(UTC-04:00) Falkland Islands',
        'America/Campo_Grande' => '(UTC-04:00) Brazil',
        'America/Goose_Bay' => '(UTC-04:00) Atlantic Time (Goose Bay)',
        'America/Glace_Bay' => '(UTC-04:00) Atlantic Time (Canada)',
        'America/St_Johns' => '(UTC-03:30) Newfoundland',
        'America/Araguaina' => '(UTC-03:00) UTC-3',
        'America/Montevideo' => '(UTC-03:00) Montevideo',
        'America/Miquelon' => '(UTC-03:00) Miquelon, St. Pierre',
        'America/Godthab' => '(UTC-03:00) Greenland',
        'America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires' => '(UTC-03:00) Buenos Aires',
        'America/Sao_Paulo' => '(UTC-03:00) Brasilia',
        'America/Noronha' => '(UTC-02:00) Mid-Atlantic',
        'Atlantic/Cape_Verde' => '(UTC-01:00) Cape Verde Is.',
        'Atlantic/Azores' => '(UTC-01:00) Azores',
        'Europe/Dublin' => '(UTC) Irish Standard Time : Dublin',
        'Europe/Lisbon' => '(UTC) Western European Time : Lisbon',
        'Europe/London' => '(GMT) Greenwich Mean Time : London, Belfast',
        'Africa/Abidjan' => '(GMT) Monrovia, Reykjavik',
        'Europe/Amsterdam' => '(UTC+01:00) Amsterdam, Berlin, Bern, Rome, Stockholm, Vienna',
        'Europe/Belgrade' => '(UTC+01:00) Belgrade, Bratislava, Budapest, Ljubljana, Prague',
        'Europe/Brussels' => '(UTC+01:00) Brussels, Copenhagen, Madrid, Paris',
        'Africa/Algiers' => '(UTC+01:00) West Central Africa',
        'Africa/Windhoek' => '(UTC+01:00) Windhoek',
        'Asia/Beirut' => '(UTC+02:00) Beirut',
        'Africa/Cairo' => '(UTC+02:00) Cairo',
        'Asia/Gaza' => '(UTC+02:00) Gaza',
        'Africa/Johannesburg' => '(UTC+02:00) Johannesburg, Harare, Pretoria',
        'Asia/Jerusalem' => '(UTC+02:00) Jerusalem',
        'Europe/Athens' => '(UTC+02:00) Athens',
        'Europe/Minsk' => '(UTC+02:00) Minsk',
        'Asia/Damascus' => '(UTC+02:00) Syria',
        'Europe/Moscow' => '(UTC+03:00) Moscow, St. Petersburg, Volgograd',
        'Africa/Addis_Ababa' => '(UTC+03:00) Nairobi',
        'Asia/Tehran' => '(UTC+03:30) Tehran',
        'Asia/Dubai' => '(UTC+04:00) Abu Dhabi, Muscat',
        'Asia/Yerevan' => '(UTC+04:00) Yerevan',
        'Asia/Kabul' => '(UTC+04:30) Kabul',
        'Asia/Yekaterinburg' => '(UTC+05:00) Ekaterinburg',
        'Asia/Tashkent' => '(UTC+05:00) Tashkent',
        'Asia/Kolkata' => '(UTC+05:30) Chennai, Kolkata, Mumbai, New Delhi',
        'Asia/Katmandu' => '(UTC+05:45) Kathmandu',
        'Asia/Dhaka' => '(UTC+06:00) Astana, Dhaka',
        'Asia/Novosibirsk' => '(UTC+06:00) Novosibirsk',
        'Asia/Rangoon' => '(UTC+06:30) Yangon (Rangoon)',
        'Asia/Bangkok' => '(UTC+07:00) Bangkok, Hanoi, Jakarta',
        'Asia/Krasnoyarsk' => '(UTC+07:00) Krasnoyarsk',
        'Asia/Hong_Kong' => '(UTC+08:00) Beijing, Chongqing, Hong Kong, Urumqi',
        'Asia/Irkutsk' => '(UTC+08:00) Irkutsk, Ulaan Bataar',
        'Australia/Perth' => '(UTC+08:00) Perth',
        'Australia/Eucla' => '(UTC+08:45) Eucla',
        'Asia/Tokyo' => '(UTC+09:00) Osaka, Sapporo, Tokyo',
        'Asia/Seoul' => '(UTC+09:00) Seoul',
        'Asia/Yakutsk' => '(UTC+09:00) Yakutsk',
        'Australia/Adelaide' => '(UTC+09:30) Adelaide',
        'Australia/Darwin' => '(UTC+09:30) Darwin',
        'Australia/Sydney' => '(UTC+10:00) Sydney, Canberra, Brisbane',
        'Australia/Hobart' => '(UTC+10:00) Hobart',
        'Asia/Vladivostok' => '(UTC+10:00) Vladivostok',
        'Australia/Lord_Howe' => '(UTC+10:30) Lord Howe Island',
        'Etc/GMT-11' => '(UTC+11:00) Solomon Is., New Caledonia',
        'Asia/Magadan' => '(UTC+11:00) Magadan',
        'Pacific/Norfolk' => '(UTC+11:30) Norfolk Island',
        'Asia/Anadyr' => '(UTC+12:00) Anadyr, Kamchatka',
        'Pacific/Auckland' => '(UTC+12:00) Auckland, Wellington',
        'Etc/GMT-12' => '(UTC+12:00) Fiji, Kamchatka, Marshall Is.',
        'Pacific/Chatham' => '(UTC+12:45) Chatham Islands',
        'Pacific/Tongatapu' => '(UTC+13:00) Nuku Alofa',
        'Pacific/Kiritimati' => '(UTC+14:00) Kiritimati'
    );
```

When dates come out of your database, they'll need to be converted from UTC into the user's timezone.

```
$timestamp = time(); // or a timestamp from your DB

# create server and user timezone objects
$fromZone = new DateTimeZone('UTC'); // UTC
$toZone = new DateTimeZone($userTimezone); // Europe/London, or whatever it happens to be

$time = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $timestamp);
$dt = new DateTime($time, $fromZone);
echo $dt->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'); // Still UTC

$dt->setTimezone($toZone);
echo $dt->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'); // Converted
```

You'll need to go through the WeBid application and modify the appropriate parts to convert properly.

---

So, using the above code, you'll need a couple of functions that do something like this:

```
function getConvertedDateTimeObject($timestamp, $userTimezone){
    # create server and user timezone objects
    $fromZone = new DateTimeZone('UTC'); // UTC
    $toZone = new DateTimeZone($userTimezone); // Europe/London, or whatever it happens to be

    $time = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $timestamp);
    $dt = new DateTime($time, $fromZone);
    $dt->setTimezone($toZone);
    return $dt;
}

function getUserTimestamp($timestamp, $userTimezone){
    $dt = getConvertedDateTimeObject($timestamp, $userTimezone);
    return $dt->getTimestamp();
}

function getUserOffset($timestamp, $userTimezone){
    $dt = getConvertedDateTimeObject($timestamp, $userTimezone);
    return $dt->getOffset();
}
```

Then in your class:

```
$this->ctime = getUserTimestamp(time(), $userTimezone); // I assume you have access to the user's timezone?
$this->tdiff = getUserOffset(time(), $userTimezone);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response, but this change involves non-trivial changes to the entire auction application scope for all dates, I'd prefer a method which would apply to $system->ctime and $system->tdiff the correct values in order to prevent large test cases and heavy QA throughout the app...

Comment: It wouldn't be difficult to implement - I've updated my answer. I hope you have access to the logged in user's timezone from within the class where ctime and tdiff are set.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative solution to bcmcfc's answer (which pretty much says it all):

Remove any timezone support from WeBid (at least disable any customization for it) and save everything as UTC (if it isn't already).

Modify the interface to display dates and timestamps using Javascript. The browser will correctly transform a unix timestamp (don't forget to multiply by 1000, Javascript's `Date` expects milliseconds, instead of seconds as in PHP) based on the settings of the browser or operating system.

For example, instead of outputting 2012-08-18 09:33:43, you would output `<script>document.write(new Date(1345282423*1000).toString());</script>`, where `1345282423` was obtained directly from the database, or using `strtotime`.

You only need to alter the function which displays dates and timestamps, and disable timezone customization (forcing UTC/GMT) (don't forget `date_default_timezone_set("UTC");`).

This seems trivial enough to me.